# Sending emails without looking like spam

Tags: asp.net, email

I want so send every week an update by email. But Im afraid that if there are too many emails sent, they will be marked as spam. Any of you has experience sending many emails (thousands) weekly? What techniques do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A good answer for this question would
>   be a real gold mine for a motivated
>   spammer :)

Not really -- as you'll see in that [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marke), answers center on showing that you are the authorative sender of the email, and various aspects that are useless to spammers and useful to non-spammers who send a lot of email.