# Vista's IIS Instance doesn't have SMTP (Solutions?)

Tags: iis, asp-classic, smtp, windows-vista

Presently, I am working on a project using classic ASP. My development machine is Vista Enterprise. Although Vista does allow you to have multiple Web Sites (not without a workaround in XP), it has removed the SMTP service from IIS.

Is there a standard workaround for this issue?

As more web developers at my company receive new machines I am concerned that this issue will become a greater irritant. (Currently I am the only Web Dev using Vista)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a better suggestion over on serverfault.
[This thread details it](https://serverfault.com/questions/64753/smtp-server-on-windows-7)

http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/ Nice tool.

Comment: I have used smtp4dev since this answer was posted as my go to dev solution. That being said I recently came across another possibility. A program called papercut. Here is a comparison of the two apps. http://improve.dk/papercut-vs-smtp4dev-testing-mail-sending-locally/

Answer (score 6):

You have two workarounds. You can direct all mail to your company's SMTP server. This often means that your development machines use a different config (remote SMTP vs local), so I find this less desirable.

You could also install another SMTP server on your dev machine. One option is the free [Mercury Mail Transport System](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercwin.htm) by the maker's of the venerable Pegasus Mail.

Comment: Looks like I really need to use CDO sys vs. CDONTS.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to "[What’s a good mail server for development use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770098/whats-a-good-mail-server-for-development-use)"

I have tried 3 things:

- [sendmail from SUA community warehouse](http://www.suacommunity.com/warehouse.htm) built with SASL (AUTH) and OpenSSL (SSL/TLS) for Interx/SFU/SUA. This works well but is quite slow to start a session for some reason. And of course it is sendmail so about as opaque to configure as humanly possible. (Services for UNIX 3.5 and the Subsystem for Unix Applications also come with an old-ish build of sendmail that does not have AUTH and ssl.)
- [Mercury Mail Server](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm). The setup and managment feels obtuse and dated to me.
- [hMailServer](http://hmailserver.com/). Very slick. Quick setup and intuitive to configure. I like it.

Comment: hMailServer also supports DKIM signatures: http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_domain.  Very nice if you don't want to get flagged as spam: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/).  It works well for my development environment on Windows 7.

Description of Papercut from the CodePlex site:

> Papercut is a simplified SMTP server designed to only receive messages
>   (not to send them on) with a GUI on top of it allowing you to see the
>   messages it receives. It doesn't enforce any restrictions on
>   addresses, it just takes the message and allows you see it. It is only
>   active while it is running, and if you want it in the background, just
>   minimize it to the system tray. When it receives a new message, a
>   balloon message will show up to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I use the built-in settings for SMTP mail to dump emails to a directory as shown in this post:
[How can I use a local SMTP server when developing on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120132/how-can-i-use-a-local-smtp-server-when-developing-on-windows-7/2734772#2734772)