# What's a good mail server for development use?

Tags: imap, pop3, mail-server

I'm doing some development which will involve reacting to emails, and I'd like to use a local IMAP mail server for this.

I currently use [Devnull SMTP server](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtp.jsp) for testing of *sending* emails, but this just logs and discards messages, it doesn't do IMAP for checking *incoming* emails/mailboxes.

I don't need/want a full-blown server, just something lightweight I can easily start/stop as required.

Multi-platform is preferred, but feel free to provide answer for specific platforms also.

(A POP3-based server would also be acceptable for development use, since I'll be supporting both in my code anyway.)

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/).

Comment: I've used hMail on several of my domains for a few years now, very slick, lightweight server.

Comment: I gave Mercury Mail Server and hMail server a whirl. hMail was much, much nicer to deal with. Easier to get installed and with a nice configurator. Very slick. (Of course, I was previously using sendmail built for SUA/Interix.)

Comment: I tried out loads for windows, you can't beat hmailserver there.

Answer (score 4):

I consider [JAMES](http://james.apache.org) the best mail server for development. And its portable too. Fully written in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Mercury Mail Server is a full featured mail server (minus webmail), however it is very light and should meet your need: [Mercury Mail Server](http://www.pmail.com/overviews/ovw_mercury.htm)

Edit: Forgot to mention Windows/Netware only

Answer (score 2):

Check out [courier](http://www.courier-mta.org) for unix-based machines.  I've run it for quite some time on a linux machine, and it's very nice.  You can easily enable/disable the features you want, including SMTP, POP, IMAP, SMTP Auth, SSL versions of protocols, etc.

Answer (score 1):

exim works nice even in windows via cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Mdaemon is an excellent windows MTA.  Lots of good reasons to use it in production too.
Another different option is to use Gammadyne mailer in server mode.

- http://www.altn.com/products/mdaemon-email-server-windows/
- http://www.hmailserver.com/
- http://www.gammadyne.com/gm-list_management.htm