# IMAP server for local develompent/testing

Tags: linux, imap

I'm developing application that will read messages from IMAP server.. what would you recommend for local development/testing (easy configurable light server)

Platform - Ubuntu Linux

Comment: http://www.gnome.sk/Dwarf/dwarf_mail.html

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770098/whats-a-good-mail-server-for-development-use

Answer (score -1, accepted):

mocking twisted imap server worked for me !

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really programming related, but for a well known open-source IMAP server you could use [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/).