# C# - Failure sending mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This code works fine on my local machine ut when I deploy it. it gives `Failure sending mail` error.. Please Help...

```
MailAddress addrsTo = new MailAddress(toEmail);
MailAddress addrsFrom = new MailAddress("XXX@XXX.com", "XXX Title");

MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage(addrsFrom, addrsTo);
mailmsg.Subject = mailSbjct;

mailmsg.Body = "XXX Body";

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.XXX.com");
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
smtp.Port = 26;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXX@XXX.com", "XXXXXXX");

try {
    smtp.Send(mailmsg);
} catch (Exception exc) {
    throw new XXXException(1234, "---" + exc.Message);

}
```

Comment: There may be a network problem, could you control your firewall settings and enable your firewall for your specific application?

Comment: what error you are getting? If your deployed machine have connection with mail client.

Comment: It gives me just "Failure sending mail".

Comment: Check your ports on the remote machine. Standard SMTP port is 25 and your code is using 26. It may be possible that it’s blocked by firewall or something.

Comment: you have not accepted the answer, hope its working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this, if you are using [gmail](http://www.gmail.com) :

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 mail.Subject = "Your Subject";
 mail.From = new MailAddress("senderMailAddress");
 mail.To.Add("ReceiverMailAddress");
 mail.Body = "Hello! your mail content goes here...";
 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
 smtp.EnableSsl = true;
 NetworkCredential netCre = new NetworkCredential("SenderMailAddress","SenderPassword" );
 smtp.Credentials = netCre;

 try
  {
   smtp.Send(mail);                
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {               
  }
```

Comment: I am using my custom address. Actually It was working last month, but yesterday I have received an email from customer that the email is not working and then I go to check and it is not working. Then I try from my local machine and it is working working fine, then I deploy the files again and the problem exist... Please Help...

Comment: then check the port number 26 is allowed in your hosting server's firewall.

Comment: suggested works with gmail account, are you using gmail account for that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26627/discussion-between-arshad-and-arahim)

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned in your question **works fine on my local machine**.

It is suggesting that the problem is of credential which you are providing to send the mail.

### Edit 1

If you are using **you own domain credential** then it is not going to work on the server.

 The user IIS should have enough authority to send mail.

IIS User More detail
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

Here is a SO link
[How to send email through IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585130/how-to-send-email-through-iis7)

Comment: How to set IIS on server?. I have my own credentials and it is working fine on my local machine. But not in server.