# php mail function..... Iam getting output as "mail failed". can you please help me to get it done

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'pradz39@gmail.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email';
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Hello";
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//send the email
$mail_sent = mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
?>
```

**i am using xampp for windows can you help me to configure smtp server.....**

output is

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in D:\installed\xampp\htdocs\mail.php on line 13
Mail failed

Comment: More data needed. Remove the error suppression operator `@` from the front of `mail` and see if it spits out an error/warning.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658043/troubleshooting-php-mail

Comment: I agree, remove the @, note the error and post it on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP mail() needs a mail relay server to actually send mail. On hosting providers, the enviroment is preconfigured and ready for use.

These are the possible solutions for you.

- In your case you must check if your xampp bundle comes with a mail server and setup/start it
- If it doesn't come with a mail server, then you need to either setup your IIS SMTP server instructions at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230235
- Or download and install a free smpt server like [Argosoft](http://www.argosoft.com/rootpages/)
- You can also use a php package that can directly connect to SMTP with authentication support and use your real smpt server (hotmail, yahoo etc, isp) for relaying. This can be done with [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php) and it worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

try removing "@".
I have tried this sample code, in which I am fetching data from input form.
there is one more method, using SMTP, if you know the SMTP server credentials you can use that way either.
Here is the sample;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your sendmail settings are correct in your `php.ini` file.  Assuming you're running *nix:

```
SMTP = myserver.localnet.com   
sendmail_from = me@localhost.com  
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

There are a few 'gotcha's with mail().  See this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658043/troubleshooting-php-mail) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

It depends a lot of the environment, like my where my site is hosted I guess mail function is disabled and does not work. So, I use SMTP and use google mail service for corporate.