# Checklist for good email delivery in php

Tags: php, email, spam

I have a PHP application that sends email using the pear Mail function. Unfortunately all my emails end up in the junk folder.

Can i get a checklist for things i should do to make sure my emails are recieved correctly.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MailChimp has [several good articles](http://www.mailchimp.com/articles/#deliverability) on effective email marketing campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote down a few points in [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658043/troubleshooting-php-mail/1658064#1658064).