# sending email via php mail function goes to spam

Tags: phpmailer, php, email-spam

I am facing problem in sending mail to my inbox (gmail account) but everytime it goes to spam folder.

Here is the code snippet

```
     //$ticketDetail is array which contain required information to send.
       sendOwnershipEmail('dineshnagarscriet@gmail.com', $ticketDetail);
    
       function sendOwnershipEmail($email, $ticketDetail) {
            $param = new stdClass();
   

$param->content = "<div>
    <div><b>".$ticketDetail[0]['ticket_number']."</b></div><br/>
    <div><img src='".$ticketDetail[0]['image_path']."'/></div><br/>
    <div>Ticket with ticket number ".$ticketDetail[0]['ticket_number']." has been requested for tranfer from <div/>
    <div>".$ticketDetail[0]['oldDepartment']." to ".$ticketDetail[0]['newDepartment']." Department <div/>
  </div>";
            
            $param->sendTo = $email;
            $param->subject = "Request for Department transfer";
            
        sendMailFunction($param);
    }
    
    
    function sendMailFunction($param) {
            $to = $param->sendTo;
            $subject = $param->subject;
            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: successive.testing@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
            $message = "<html><head>" .
                   "<meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='en-us'>" .
                   "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1252'>" .
                   "</head><body>" .$param->content.        
                   "<br><br></body></html>";
          mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
```

And I have tried a lot like setting headers as  Reply-To, Return-Path etc but every time it goes to spam.

Can you please figure out whats the problem?

Comment: As I know, Mail providers like Yahoo! send emails with PHP to spam folder. Also, I would be good to know a liitle about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: HTML parts are valid when its param values are double quoted: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">` like this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is simple that the PHP-Mail function is not using a well configured SMTP Server.

Nowadays Email-Clients and Servers perform massive checks on the emails sending server, like Reverse-DNS-Lookups, Graylisting and whatevs. All this tests will fail with the php mail() function. If you are using a dynamic ip, its even worse.

Use the PHPMailer-Class and configure it to use smtp-auth along with a well configured, dedicated SMTP Server (either a local one, or a remote one) and your problems are gone.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 16):

#### Try changing your headers to this:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: successive.testing@gmail.com" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: successive.testing@gmail.com" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

**For a few reasons.**

- One of which is the need of a `Reply-To` and,
- The use of apostrophes instead of double-quotes. Those two things in my experience with forms, is usually what triggers a message ending up in the Spam box.

You could also try changing the `$from` to:

```
$from = "successive.testing@gmail.com";
```

---

---

### EDIT:

See these links I found on the subject https://stackoverflow.com/a/9988544/1415724 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16717647/1415724 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899837/1415724

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5944155/1415724 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532320/1415724

- Try using the SMTP server of your ISP.

  Using this apparently worked for many: `X-MSMail-Priority: High`

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=931932

*"My host helped me to enable DomainKeys and SPF Records on my domain and now when I send a test message to my Hotmail address it doesn't end up in Junk.
It was actually really easy to enable these settings in cPanel under Email Authentication. I can't believe I never saw that before.
It only works with sending through SMTP using phpmailer by the way. Any other way it still is marked as spam."*

PHPmailer sending mail to spam in hotmail. how to fix
http://pastebin.com/QdQUrfax

Comment: Hi Fred tried your suggested changes but didn't solve problem. any other idea?

Comment: If by apostrophes you meant single quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

What would the `$from` do in that script?

Comment: @Lenin I call them apostrophes. For example I've just used one now. As for 'single quotes' are the same character on my/the keyboard.

Comment: ok i just added $from variable for testing purpose like passing fifth parameter in php mail function.

Comment: Hi @DineshNagar. Very strange. I used single quotes in headers before and they always landed in the Spam box. When I switched to double quotes, all was fine.

Comment: Please read the thread I shared. Single quotes do not parse strings. He rather used them correctly in most places.

Comment: @DineshNagar there's no place for fifth parameter if you do not enclose it with the necessary HTML in `mail()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Lenin Yes I am familiar with that same post/article. However and contrary to popular belief, is not an exact science, so I beg to differ on that subject, yet I am not denying it neither. Many modify headers to their liking, skipping certain steps etc. With the forms I build, I always follow the same steps and never have I had one end up in the Spam box. That is by "my" own experience of course. However that article does not mention anything about `mail()` and is a completely different "animal".

Comment: SO answers should not come up with just opinions. Single quotes used correctly does the job well. 

He rather used the double quotes wrong in the following:
` "<meta http-equiv='Content-Language' content='en-us'>" .
               "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=windows-1252'>" `

Comment: @DineshNagar I just noticed something. Try it again, yet make sure there are dots to concatenate the `headers` and that the first one has none before the `=` sign, but all others will have `.=` I missed a dot in the second one in my answer.

Comment: @Lenin Those are not part of the headers Lenin. That is completely seperate. (meta tags) and they can be used.

Comment: Fred i already added .= for headers that u missed in your answer but problem still exist.

Comment: @DineshNagar Hmm... well I noticed something that may be breaking something. You have a few `<div/>` that need to be changed to `</div>` try that. I've seen broken DIVs halt scripts altogether, last week actually.

Comment: @DineshNagar I'm curious about this `$param->content = "<div>` how is that being used?

Comment: $param->content = "<div>....</div>" just for creating message along with image and finally embeded this in sendMailFunction() function's message variable.

Comment: @DineshNagar I added a few links for you to look into. Look under my **EDIT**, I hope you will be able to find some answers in there. I am at a loss now.

Comment: @DineshNagar So, any luck with the added info I included?

Comment: Ahh pain only still goes to spam :(

Answer (score 5):

If you are sending this through your own mail server you might need to add a "Sender" header which will contain an email address of from your own domain. Gmail will probably be spamming the email because the FROM address is a gmail address but has not been sent from their own server.

Answer (score 2):

What we usually do with e-mail, preventing spam-folders as the end destination, is using either Gmail as the smtp server or [Mandrill](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23737696-How-do-I-send-with-PHPMailer-) as the smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I have observed is likely the email address you're providing is not a valid email address at the domain. like Nobody@gmail.com. The email should be existing at Google Domain. I had alot of issues before figuring that out myself... Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your tests. If you in your form you put the **same email as the email address which must receive** it will be directly in spam :)