# Php mail spam only for live id

Tags: php, email

```
$headers = '';
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $fromName <$from>" . "\n";
$headers .= "Cc: " . "\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: $bcc" . "\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: successive.testing@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f reply@xyz.com');
```

**It's working fine when i am sending mail in gmail id but when try to send mail at live,    yahoo id then mail going to spam.
  What reason may be?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229279/sending-email-via-php-mail-function-goes-to-spam

That answer might help you as well.

Comment: Try carriage-return in all the lines \r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding following

```
$headers = "From: myplace@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: myplace2@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: myplace@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: sombodyelse@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: hidden@example.com\r\n";
```

These links will help you
http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AvoidingFpsForSenders

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 0):

If it was possible to know what makes an email go to spam, all spam authors would know a way to avoid getting to spam.
So really, there's nothing that anyone can say that will prevent your email from going to spam for sure.

In this case, however, I think the biggest problem is you do not use [Sender Policy Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), which proves that the the sender is real.

Since anyone can write anything in the `From` header, it makes sense why spam filters tend to dislike emails that do not prove their origin.