# Email going to SPAM in yahoo and URL not working

Tags: php, html-email

I write a script to send email from my website. I recieve email in inbox in gmail, outlook and hotmail but in yahoo, its going to `SPAM` folder and also URL in not working in yahoo. Whats wrong in my code,
**Header**

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: $Name <$Email> \r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $Email\r\n";
```

**Message with URL**

```
$message.= "<a href='https://www.google.com'>Click here</a>";
```

Comment: Welcome to the dark art of emailing, please leave your soul at the door.... Also links are disabled in spam messages. You need to move it to your inbox in Yahoo for the link to work

Comment: @superphonic yes I want to move it to inbox in yahoo, can you please tell me where am I wrong

Comment: Unfortunately not, there are more than a few things that need putting in place. The answer below by Rakesh is a good place to start, but by no means exhaustive. Using a proper SMTP gateway is a good place to start, then you have domain SPF Records, DKIM Signing etc...

Answer (score 1):

PHP-Mail function is not uses a well configured SMTP Server so may be this is a reason or try to Use the [PHPMailer-Class](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). or you need to try with full headers

Also links not working cause your mail in spam. need to move in inbox and see.

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/

For more info follow:- [sending email via php mail function goes to spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229279/sending-email-via-php-mail-function-goes-to-spam)