# Mail go to spam instead of inbox and some errors in header part of mail using PHP

Tags: php

i am trying for send mail using php.My mail go to spam and some other errors are also in mail.

My header code is

```
$header_mail="select content from mail_header where id='1'";
$header_mail2=mysql_query($header_mail);
$fet=mysql_fetch_array($header_mail2);

$content= htmlentities($fet['content']);

$Headers = "From:$content\r\n" . 
"Reply-To:$content\r\n" . 
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; 
$Headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$Headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset= iso-8859-1\n";
```

data in $content is `zamisoft<zamisoft.com>` but i got the mail as with

```
from:    Zamisoft&lt
```

reply-to:     Zamisoft&lt,
    zamisoft@gmail.com&gt

I got the these message in mail

"Be careful with this message. Many people marked similar messages as phishing scams, so this might contain unsafe content.  Learn more "

Mail is going to spam and errors are in header section part of mail.

Any body help me for solve these issue?

Comment: Did you see your mail server configuration?

Comment: What is the mail server do you use?

Comment: mail id is not created in server.mail send for any maild

Comment: This post regarding the same issue.look at this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229279/sending-email-via-php-mail-function-goes-to-spam

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple that the PHP `mail()` function is not using a well configured **SMTP Server**.

Nowadays Email-Clients and Servers perform massive checks on the emails sending server, like Reverse-DNS-Lookups, Graylisting and whatevs. All this tests will fail with the php `mail()` function. If you are using a dynamic ip, its even worse.

Use the `PHPMailer-Class` and configure it to use `smtp-auth` along with a well configured, dedicated **SMTP Server** (either a local one, or a remote one) and your problems are gone.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

remove the `htmlentities()` from `$content= htmlentities($fet['content']);` and then try!

Since you are already setting the **Content Type** and **Character Encoding**, the contents of the array `$fet['content']` will be read properly by the browsers!

`htmlentities()` converts the html tags to htmlentities (eg. `<` to `&lt;`) which is what you are facing!!

Try it and let us know if the problem persists

Remove the line "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; as you have defined the header in the last line of header.

Add $Headers   .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()."\r\n"; at the last line of your code.

It tells which version of php is being used!

Also the email address should be a valid one as well!!

Comment: Now got mail in inbox, and header is correct,but shows these massage  'This message may not have been sent by: zamisoft@gmail.com  Learn more  Report phishing ' in mail

Comment: I have edited my answer above. Try and let me know if it works

Comment: shows the same error....C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini....shows the same error This message may not have been sent by: zamisoft@gmail.com  Learn more  Report phishing