# Warning Message "This message may not have been sent by: sender@gmail.com Learn more Report phishing " in php

Tags: php

I am trying for send mail using php.But got these warning message in mail. 'This message may not have been sent by: zamisoft@gmail.com  Learn more  Report phishing.

My header is

```
$header_mail="select content from mail_header where id='1'";
$header_mail2=mysql_query($header_mail);
$fet=mysql_fetch_array($header_mail2);

$content= $fet['content'];

$Headers = "From:$content\r\n" . 
"Reply-To:$content\r\n" . 
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n"; 
$Headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
 $Headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()."\r\n";
```

Content in $content variable is `zamisoft<zamisoft@gmail.com>`

Any body help me for solve these issue?

Answer (score 3):

I'd already answered the same on your previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26011233/725306) but it is more relevant here.

The problem is simple that the PHP `mail()` function is not using a well configured **SMTP Server**.

Nowadays Email-Clients and Servers perform massive checks on the emails sending server, like Reverse-DNS-Lookups, Graylisting and whatevs. All this tests will fail with the php `mail()` function. If you are using a dynamic ip, its even worse.

Use the `PHPMailer-Class` and configure it to use `smtp-auth` along with a well configured, dedicated **SMTP Server** (either a local one, or a remote one) and your problems are gone.

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: i cant understand your saying,,,where i got these code?

Comment: use the last link of [github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). There you can see on the right, at the end a button `Download Zip`

Comment: read the [readme.md](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md) which help you understand how to use the `PHPMailer` class

Comment: also, you need to search for configuring SMTP. Have a try yourself or ask a new question

Comment: Downloed that code and put into my server.I had created a test file,try for send mail,at the time shows these error 'Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed'.

Comment: have you followed the instructions in [readme.md](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: @shilnamk: have you been able to send the mail?