# Email not reaching a specific email domain from php or C#

Tags: c#, php, smtp

I am currently using an Office 365 account to send email from various websites.  I have implemented an smtp client in both php and C# to send the mail.  I use GoDaddy and Rackspace to hosts my sites.

The mail reaches most address without issue, however, I have a business domain through Google, which ends with .co, and emails do not make it to my inbox there.

Here are the settings for the PHPMailer client:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '<myuser>';
$mail->Password = '<mypassword>';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->setFrom('noreply@<mymaildomain>.com', 'MyMail');
```

The settings send email find to yahoo, gmail, etc.  However, when I try to send it to my .co email address, the client indicates the mail was sent, but it never shows up in the inbox.

I am wondering if it is an issue with a domain in Google or if the .co is the problem.  Is there any special setting I need to make on the client for .co addresses?

**UPDATE**

I changed phpmailer to simply use php's mail function.  The mail was sent through to my .co domain, but I still have no idea why it will not go through when an authenticated SMTP user sends it.  I can go into my Office 365 account and send email to the .co address without issue.  I just cannot push it from the server.  My host server does not contain the smtp server.

Comment: ask client to check spam folder... maybe it there. If email really in spam folder then here a some descriptions how to fix it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229279/sending-email-via-php-mail-function-goes-to-spam

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is not in the spam folder.  I am sending email alerts to myself and other team members and have checked to make sure it was not in the spam folder.  Thanks.