# How to Send Email from PHP With and Without Mail()

Tags: php, email, exim, exim4

Is there anyway to improve a PHP `mail()` call like the following to lower the risk of having it being classified as spam by providers like Gmail?

```
$to      = "alice@somewhere.com";
$subject = "One Last Step to Get Started";
$message = "To get going with your account on example.com, just click the link below. Thanks for signing up!\r\n\r\nhttp://example.com/?echeck=$id\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nDidn't sign up for example.com? Probably someone typed in your address by mistake. If you want, you can tell us but there's no need.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nBest,\r\nThe team";
$headers = 'From: alerts@example.com' . "\r\n" .
   'Reply-To: contact@example.com' . "\r\n" .
   'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Right now, services such as Gmail usually mark this as spam and mail-tester.com gave it a score of 3.6/10, for the most part because the DKIM record wasn't valid (I have no idea where `mail()` is getting the record it's using).

If it's not possible to improve a `mail()` request, is there a better way to send email from a PHP website without using an outside service? I already have Exim4 installed on my server, so is it possible to use that? I want an easily customization and expandable solution with a limited amount of code, something similar to `mail()` but with more features.

Comment: You may check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229279/sending-email-via-php-mail-function-goes-to-spam

Comment: @ChrysUgwu Thanks, that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use services like [Mailgun](https://mailgun.com). It provides an API for sending an email. It has a library for PHP.