# Contact Form Not Working - php file is returning the "else" failed response

Tags: php, contact-form

I have tried looking in similar questions posted here, but cannot find an answer (got about 1900 questions popping up).

I have a contact form on a page at a site I am creating on the webpage hosting site
https://www.one.com/en/

Here is the form on the page contact/contact.shtml

```
<form action="contact/mail.php" method="post"><br>
    Your name<br>
    <input type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
    Your e-mail<br>
    <input type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
    Message<br>
    <textarea name="cf_message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Here is the content of the contact/mail.php file

```
<?php
    $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
    $field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
    $mail_to = 'clashton@gmail.com';
    $subject = ' Contact Form '.$field_name;
    $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
    $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
    if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact.shtml';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to clashton@gmail.com');
        window.location = 'contact.shtml';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

When I try to send a message a window pops up containing the error message "Message failed. Please, send an email to clashton@gmail.com". In other words the "else" action is happening.

If it seems that this question has a trivial answer, please keep in mind that I am completely new at this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Drop `if($mail_status)` and try `if(mail($mail_to,$subject,$body_message,$headers)){`   on its own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699070/php-mail-form-isnt-working/33704535#33704535

Comment: When you get your form working you will also find it difficult to get emails sent if the `"From:"` address is not an address on your own server. Use the email address from your form as a `"Reply-To:"` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948622/php-mail-function-server-and-localhost-not-working/33948920#33948920

Comment: Steve, Thanks for the tips. I followed all of them but nothing worked until I changed the email address (mine) to one on the server, and now it works.

Comment: Glad to hear that - most email services are pretty tight on that nowadays. Emails don't even get as far as being considered as spam without that. Well done.