# PHP mail() function server and localhost not working

Tags: php, function, email

I am trying to send a simple email on one of my web pages.

`mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'NEW ORDER', 'order details');`

The code does not work on my xampp localhost, nor my server. (i received no emails).
I read about having to edit a php.ini file on my server, but it seemed to allow it (based on my minuscule knowledge).

`[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/sendmail -oi -t`

## Any ideas?

My main goal is to be able to send it on my actual website. (im not as worried about the actual localhost)

Comment: Are you using a shared server?

Comment: Not using a shared sever. Ill check that other article out Nic.

Comment: Your server DNS are configured? I had the same issue - google rejects wrong domain names. Also it is recommended to look through maillog for errors

Comment: Domain is correct. ill check out the maillog.

Comment: use test mail server tool for xampp..worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that the email "From" address is a valid address which exists on your server - see my answers among others

[Authenticate Email PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526210/authenticate-email-php/33851526#33851526)

And you need a "From" on your `mail();` - which you appear to be missing - see

[PHP mail form isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699070/php-mail-form-isnt-working/33704535#33704535)

Add a "Reply-To:" header and use the email address which you get from your user in that, so that you receive an email which you can reply to rather than it defaulting to going to your server.

Other useful comments:
[PHP mail not working for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803994/php-mail-not-working-for-some-reason)

My personal favourite solution also recommended by plenty of others: PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Chapter and verse on emailing from scripts: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail