# PHP mail() Not Working

Tags: php, ubuntu, sendmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Troubleshooting PHP Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658043/troubleshooting-php-mail)

I can't seem to get mail using PHP's mail() function.  I am working on my client's dev server, which is running a version of Ubuntu.  I installed sendmail using the following command:  apt-get install sendmail.  After that I went to the php.ini file in  /etc/php5/apache2/ and took out the comment for sendmail_path and set it to /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -t.  Despite this, I'm still not getting any mail.

Comment: Have you tried using a script that uses `mail()` itself and check if there are any warnings or errors?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite likely that sendmail itself is not set up correctly. Can you receive a test message sent with the `sendmail` command? E.g.: `echo "test message" | sendmail -s "test message" your-email@your-domain.com`

Comment: you stole my answer! but before you do anything check if sendmail is actually sending mail to outside word rather than spooling them back on the box

Comment: No, I'm not getting anything at all.

Comment: Uh, so what's next.  Obviously sendmail is not set up correctly.  I'm bot well-versed in Linux, so I'm not sure how to proceed to ensure that it is set up correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting up sendmail is a lot of work. I would recommend you try and set up [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) or [ssmtp](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/132006) instead. If you really need a full-blown MTA, I would recommend using [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) instead.

Comment: Thanks.  If I use ssmtp or postfix will I have to remove the sendmail package from the server?