# Sending emails with CentOS sendemail doesn't work

Tags: php, email, centos, sendmail

I'm unable to send emails in php 7.3 using **mail**() - it returns **true** but **sendmail** doesn't work.

- CentOS 8
- Postfix and Sendmail: Installed and running
- Mail sent with Sendmail: no errors (below) but no email - including
  the SPAM folder php.ini SMTP = mail.levaweb.com
- AApanel: installed -  sending emails from here works

I've seen these posts:

[Troubleshooting PHP Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658043/troubleshooting-php-mail)

https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/sendmail-in-php-complete-guide/

*Test - SSH*

`echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v myemail@gmail.com`

```
220 server1.levaweb.com ESMTP Postfix
>>> EHLO server1.levaweb.com
250-server1.levaweb.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 102400000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
>>> STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>>> EHLO server1.levaweb.com
250-server1.levaweb.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 102400000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
>>> MAIL From:<root@server1.levaweb.com> SIZE=23 AUTH=root@server1.levaweb.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
>>> RCPT To:<myemail@gmail.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
>>> .
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4CB6C40096
myemail@gmail.com... Sent (Ok: queued as 4CB6C40096)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Thank you

Comment: `250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4CB6C40096
myemail@gmail.com... Sent (Ok: queued as 4CB6C40096)` It looks like the email is being sent. Check your gmail spam box.

Comment: You might want to change the From address in case of post-send bouncebacks

Answer (score 1):

I found a way out by installing [rainloop](https://www.rainloop.net) web server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).