# Avoiding email being marked as spam when sent through gmail mail server

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

Hi all (before closing based on the title, please read the bottom parragraph),

I'm having some small issues with emails being sent out from the C#/ASP.Net webapp that I'm currently developing.

We don't send emails out on mass, only to a single address, sometimes with a CC address.

The emails we are sending out contain one attached file, which is a single page PDF file (They are actually invoices in PDF format).

It's happened a couple of times that our emails have been flagged as spam. The content of the email is HTML without any images, and the HTML itself is not very complicated at all (Simply 4 p tags and an a tag with a mail to).

We have a company domain set up using the Gmail smtp server, and the email account with we use to send this email is called automated.emailer.

When created the System.Net.MailMessage, I am adding a simple name to the which is "XXX invoicing" (XXX is substituting our company name) using the MailAddress constructor which takes a display name, a replyto address of Invoicing@example.com and the from address is automated.emailer@example.com. The content has been checked against many sp

These emails are fairly important, so we need to do all we can to avoid them being caught as spam. I would appreciate any ideas on why these emails would be considered spam? It may be that, in order to make sure the IP of our domain matches the IP of the mail server, we need to install an exchange. This seems like a strong approach and I'd be keen to see if anyone has solved this problem in another way.

I have tried to ask this question with as much info as possible, to avoid this question being closed, since i've seen many questions regarding email spam closed with a reference to the below question, which I read, but didn't find an answer to my question.

[How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marke)

Comment: Belogs to supersuer.com rather than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) rather than here. But have you tried looking at [SPF](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/spf.html) records? Might boost your credibility to spam filters.

Answer (score 0):

I use the free service over at Port25. You send an email to their verifier address and get a reply with a pretty detailed breakdown of your ham score:

http://www.port25.com/support/authentication-center/email-verification/