# Gmail and Hotmail marked as spam

Tags: php, email

First of all, I want to thank you for your time. I'm having a hard time getting my head around this problem.

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845551/php-mail-function-legitimate-mail) thread we've dediced to implement PHPMailer. This however worked fine untill we've dediced to change the IP adress of the Exim deamon running on the system. Now, Hotmail and GMail both mark us as spam although we've got correct rDNS etc. We've also taken part in the Microsoft Sender ID and Junk Email Reporting program, but that still won't help us.

You can see an output of the php script running here(http://koopte.be/mailtest/test/examples/test.php).

Also, some mail headers from GMail:

> Delivered-To: myemail@gmail.com
>   Received: by 10.227.133.10 with SMTP id d10cs153720wbt;
>           Sun, 17 Oct 2010 02:44:10 -0700 (PDT)
>   Received: by 10.227.37.8 with SMTP id v8mr3118896wbd.37.1287308647612;
>           Sun, 17 Oct 2010 02:44:07 -0700 (PDT)
>   Return-Path: 
>   Received: from drt01.dco.fusa.be ([81.95.119.6])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTP id ep1si12575868wbb.6.2010.10.17.02.44.06;
>           Sun, 17 Oct 2010 02:44:07 -0700 (PDT)
>   Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 81.95.119.6 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of admin@drt01.dco.fusa.be) client-ip=81.95.119.6;
>   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 81.95.119.6 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of admin@drt01.dco.fusa.be) smtp.mail=admin@drt01.dco.fusa.be
>   Received: from admin by drt01.dco.fusa.be with local (Exim 4.69)
>    (envelope-from )
>    id 1P7Pmg-0001qb-Gg
>    for myemail@gmail.com; Sun, 17 Oct 2010 11:44:06 +0200
>   To: 
>   Subject: Koopte.be
>   X-PHP-Script: www.koopte.be/mailtest/test/examples/test_smtp_advanced_no_auth.php for 84.31.105.128
>   Date: Sun, 17 Oct 2010 11:44:06 +0200
>   From: "Koopte.be" 
>   Reply-to: "Koopte.be" 
>   Message-ID: 
>   X-Priority: 3
>   X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>    boundary="b1_f102f7049d61084cf6a8ef51cf0e57bc"
>   Sender:

Our log shows the following, which seems OK to me:

```
2010-10-17 02:33:30 1P7HBn-0000l7-Ro => email F=<admin@drt01.dco.fusa.be> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=1475 H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [209.85.227.27] C="250 2.0.0 OK 1287275610 v32si21774961weq.142"
```

Thank you for your time!

Edit: rDNS is being fixed as we speak.

---

rDNS is set now, come on guys, what am I missing?

Google reports this in the headers:

Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 81.95.119.6 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of admin@drt01.dco.fusa.be) client-ip=81.95.119.6;

But my SPF is this:

domainname. TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:81.95.119.6 ~all"

Comment: If it looks like you're not getting any answers here, head over to http://superuser.com.

Comment: What makes you think the rDNS for `81.95.119.6` is OK? `From`, `Return-Path`, rDNS & IP seem thoroughly unrelated.... If it's _your_ IP address, you might want to set it to something related to `koopte.be`, and add it to your SPF records.

Comment: +1 for SPF. Highly checked by Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

You should setup an SPF record for your domain.  Google is only returning neutral on your SPF check.

Comment: I already did (see mxtoolbox.com for the domein), but Google still says neutral. rDNS maybe?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest using Swiftmailer over PHPMailer. But regardless, your issue isn't what software you are using to send your email. You should head over to http://mxtoolbox.com/ and see what it says about your email domain. You should have the correct reverse DNS setup, in addition to making sure you have a SPF record setup in your DNS.

It seems your reverse DNS is not setup correctly, at least not for koopte.be.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that if the new IP address has been previously blacklisted by Google or Hotmail or any of the third parties they use (even before it was owned by you), the blacklist is still in effect.

In addition to mxtoolbox.com, I'd also checkout Spamhaus's lookup (http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso). Many providers use their XBL, PBL, and DBL advisories to maintain a blacklist.

Comment: I did the lookup you requested and it's all OK. In addition, I've edited the DNS records (like i did before, but it didn't work, so I changed them back, should have mentioned that). Now we'll just have to wait for the TTL to come by.

I'll update this topic once this is done.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into DKMS/DomainKeys (and Microsoft/Hotmail has their own thing as well that is similar but different for Hotmail :P)

Answer (score 0):

Spam issue because of following reasons

1)Shared hosting

If you are using shared hosting, PHP is not the solutions for this issue.try to contact your server providers.Some time your hosted IP treated as spam.Try to change the hosting providers, It may work fine.

2) More Links in your e-mail body

3 )Partial header(Always use reply-to,Ref Ans:TrentonMcManus)

4) Bulk E-Mailing

5) Spam Reporting(number of people who have clicked on your link as spam)

6) The message not to be too short or too long.

7) Sending From Blacklisted IP(hosting, and SMTP server) )

It may be new your IP address has been previously blacklisted by Google or Hotmail You can check Blacklisted ip or not from the site from here

8)Verifying sender IP

Sender Policy Framework (SPF) is an email validation system designed to prevent email spam by detecting email spoofing, a common vulnerability, by verifying sender IP addresses.

Perhaps PHP not solutions for this. You can do Following things in php coding

1)Always use the from/reply to address

2)Add unsubscribe link in body

3)Avoid spam keywords.

4)The message not to be too short or too long.

5)Text version is better than HTML