# Cakephp emails going to spam

Tags: email, cakephp, spam

I am sending email using cakephps email function. The email sends correctly but it is going to the spam folder.

Can anyone sugggest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked

Comment: I like the article link on this..Thank you very much..really usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many causes:

- The email's content looks like spam (lots of links within a little amount of text, too much alpha-numeric gibberish, certain common spam words)
- The server from which you're sending the emails has been black-listed
- The email is not properly formatted (so in your case, check that you're using CakePHP's email function fully correctly)

I would try to send a good length, regular email without any links, as if you were writing to a friend, and see if it's a content issue. If the server you're emailing from has been identified as a source of spam and is black-listed by an ISP, there's not a whole lot you can change about that.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen due to your mail content.
   Check your mail contents that contain somethings that spam filter count.