# Emails are going in spam in cake php

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, sendmail

Here are my code:-

```
//Sending mail
if ($this->Session->read('Enrollment.personalinfo_language') == 'English') {
    $language = "english";
    $subject = "Thank you for submitting your enrollment request to Apna Energy.";
} else {
    $language = "spanish";
    $subject = "Gracias por enviar su solicitud de inscripci?n a Apna Energy.";
}
$details = $this->Session->read('Enrollment');
$details['plan_name'] = $product['Product']['name'];
$details['rate'] = $plan_rate;
$details['term'] = $product['Term']['term'];
$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
$this->Email->from = 'Apna Energy <contact@apnaenergy.com>';
$this->Email->to = $this->Session->read('Enrollment.personalinfo_first_name') . ' ' . $this->Session->read('Enrollment.personalinfo_last_name') . '<' . $this->Session->read('Enrollment.personalinfo_email') . '>';
$this->Email->bcc = array('my@mail.com');
$this->Email->subject = $subject;
$this->set('details', $details);
if ($this->Session->read('Enrollment.personalinfo_language') == 'English') {
    $template = "enrollment_confirmation";
} else {
    $template = "enrollment_confirmation";
}
$this->Email->template = $template;
$this->Email->send();
```

My problem is if customer fill form they are receiving mail in his/her spam folder.. customer's mail id in "to".. and my mail id in "BCC" for me mail are coming fine in my inbox folder..

I followed two URL but they didn't work out for me..

[Cakephp emails going to spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215013/cakephp-emails-going-to-spam)

[How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

Guide me in right direction..
Thanks!!

Comment: Please format your question to make it readable.

Comment: I have formated code clearely..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by using SMTP

with normal PHP your server must be configured properly which is not easy to do as a beginner (MX records need to match the servers ip etc).
So just always stick to SMTP as mailing gateway and you will be fine.

PS: I don't think it has anything to do with your code in general, although it is not very beautiful. for instance: you should cast the array you read from the session to avoid notices thrown:

```
$details = (array)$this->Session->read('Enrollment');
```

Comment: what did you do? what are your smtp configs passed on to the email component? (no actual data/passwords, just how you did it - some code)

Comment: +1 and answer accepted. You are right, I config SMTP for free trail ... and implement it now it is working fine.. thanks @mark