# PHP my notices end up in yahoo and Hotmail Spam when using sendmail

Tags: html, email, sendmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My E-Mails Always Go To Spam Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573134/my-e-mails-always-go-to-spam-folder)

I'm building a website where i need to send notification to users via email

but after some tests i noticed that yahoo and hotmail are prone to mark as spam it

i'm sending html email (no plain text)

what rues should i follow for a perfect email html markup?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+email+spam