# Prevent mail beeing marked as spam

Tags: email, email-spam

I'm wondering how to prevent my emails from my site being marked as spam? 
I'm using sendmail.

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Do not send spam and close open relay ;) But I agree with Paul this question should be moved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this article the other day and it feels like a shame to hoard it:

[How To Ensure Your E-mail Gets Delivered](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/how-to-ensure-your-email-gets-delivered/)

It covers a good range of topics wrt. hard/soft bounces, limits, reverse-lookups, blacklists, etc. and gives recommendations for dealing with different situations.

Happy ... spamming? :)