# Send mail via out.php in order to track clicks of a button

Tags: php, email, tracking, urlencode, urldecode

I need to track a button every time someone clicks on it. I created a file "out.php" to send me an email and redirect to a link outside my page. This code redirects but the mail doesn't send.

```
<div class="buyprod">
<a target="_blank" href="http://xxx.com/out.php?url=<?php echo urlencode($this->product['from'])?>">
<img src="http://xxx.com/buybtn.jpg" alt="buy"/>
</a>
</div>
```

out.php

```
<?php
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
header("Location: ".$url);
$message = "Someone clicked buy: ";
$link = $this->product['from'];
mail('xxx@xxx.com', '@Buy', $message.$link);
exit;
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with this code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a class `$this->product['from']` that does not exist in `out.php`. This will make your file error out. Also, you need to set a 'From:' header when using `mail()`. see [stackoverflow.com/questions/6988051/php-mail-function-headers#6988085](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988051/php-mail-function-headers#6988085)

Change `out.php` to -

```
<?php
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$message = "Someone clicked buy: ";
$link = $_GET['url'];
mail('xxx@xxx.com', '@Buy', $message.$link, 'From: email@website.com');
header("Location: ".$url);
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `header()` to the end, right before `exit`

Also, your mail function should follow the following format:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I tried moving header() before exit and now it doesn't redirect. Also no mail is beeing sent.

Comment: It opens in another window this blanck page: http://mysite.com/out.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yyy.com.%2FProduct-jeans-12844.html

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `$this->product['from']` which does doesn't exist in your out.php