# sendgrid email send via codeigniter is received as spam

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, html-email, sendgrid

I am using Codeigniter and SendGrid for send my emails to the users...

I have a template for each email i send and for registration it looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Activate account for <?php echo $identity;?></h1>
    <p>Please click this link to <?php echo anchor('auth/activate/'. $id .'/'. $activation, 'Activate Your Account');?>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I use a **from** `email address` that doesn't exist like `no-reply@domain.com`

The problem is that the email is received as spam which i want to fix... could it be because of the fake **from** email address?

I guess the HTML is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to these questions as this basically has nothing to do with CI/SG, but is a general email problem that usually leads to the context and header issues:

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/48428/how-to-send-emails-and-avoid-them-being-classified-as-spam
2. http://www.allspammedup.com/2009/09/7-ways-to-prevent-your-emails-being-blocked-as-spam/
3. [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked/598#598)