# codeigniter Mail to going to Spam any solution

Tags: php, codeigniter, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

I am sending using codeigniter email library. i am usimg SMTP PROTOCOL.

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config = array(
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'mail_path' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'
        );
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from("xxxx@gmail.com","xxxx");        
        $message = "Dear Admin,<br /><br />";
    $this->email->subject('Notification');
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();
```

Email is sending perfectly but its going to spam. I want to inbox

Answer (score 0):

That example is triggering gmail's spam filter.  Provide some actual content with wording that looks important.  Or at least not like spam.

```
$message = "Dear firstname lastname,<br /><br />As you have chosen on the setup page, you are receiving this message to indicate that the requested threshold has been reached.";
$this->email->subject('Notification for recurring bill payment');
$this->email->message($message);
```

Comment: No this is not actually content, its just an example but content is actual and it doesnt seems like spam...

Comment: but there is a LINK, is it make problem?

Comment: @AlizainPrasla:  Try iteratively stripping out elements of the message and sending to see what is triggering the spam assessment.