# Bulk Email Sending

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have a list in `Outlook`.

I need to send email to every one in that list.

One of my friends suggested to use `Microsoft Exchange`.

Is it safe using `Microsoft Exchange`.I don't want to get my sent emails `Spammed`.

Can anyone suggest me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the spam perspective, so from the question perspective, there is no difference if you use MS Exchange or something else.

For not be treated like a spam, you have to sutisfy at leaset 2 rules of destination:

1. Actually do not contain any spam (links to porn and stuff like this)
2. Sutisfy other rules of the spam filter of mail server of destination

For more detailed explanation can have a look on:

[How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

Answer (score 0):

If the emails are not spam and the people you are sending the emails know you and have your address as friends or whatever it should get through just like any other bulk email send.