# How to avoid email sent through php getting into spam folder?

Tags: php, email, email-spam

I have a process which sends email to user with a confirmation link after registering into my website. But the mail goes into the spam folder of emails. I tried many codes from internet, but none seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
/** Check Spam**/
$mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST['email']);
if ($mailcheck == FALSE) {
    browse ("Invalid input");
}else{
$to = $email;
$subject = "Please Verify Your Email Address";
$header = "From: example@example.com";
$message.= "Please Click On The Link Below To Confirm Your Email Address With Us";
$message.=" ";
$message.= "www.mylink.com/subdomain/verification.php?user_verification=$code";

$sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Comment: Typically spam handling involves a variety of factors, many of them beyond your code (e.g. what IP address the mail is coming from, whether you've gotten it whitelisted in major email handlers' lists, et cetera).

Comment: and what are the other possibilities

Comment: Take a look at [the top question in the "Related" list on the right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked?rq=1).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding MIME version helped me

```
$headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset= iso-8859-1\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

- Ensure you have no white text in your email, this almost guarantees a
  spam decision
- If you’re on a shared host, consider buying a unique IP for yourself,
  because others using your IP may have gotten your IP blacklisted for
  spam
- Ensure you do not send more than 250 emails to each provider per
  hour, as your reputation (of your IP) grows with the email providers
  you can up this number
- Give your users unsubscribe link and view in browser link, if they
  cannot see the email properly they will mark you as spam, if they no
  longer want emails for you they will mark you as spam. The outcome is
  the same; being marked as spam makes it more likely your emails go
  straight into the spam folder on the provider in the future

Code such as this can be used to establish the email provider;

```
        $exploded  = explode('@', $To);
        $exploded2 = explode('.', $exploded[1]);

        switch (strtolower($exploded2[0]))
        {
            case 'hotmail':    $Network = 'Microsoft'; break;
            case 'outlook':    $Network = 'Microsoft'; break;
            case 'live':       $Network = 'Microsoft'; break;
            case 'gmail':      $Network = 'Google'; break;
            case 'googlemail': $Network = 'Google'; break;
            case 'yahoo':      $Network = 'Yahoo'; break;
            case 'ymail':      $Network = 'Yahoo'; break;
            case 'rocketmail': $Network = 'Yahoo'; break;
            case 'aol':        $Network = 'AOL'; break;
            case 'talktalk':   $Network = 'TalkTalk'; break;
            default:           $Network = 'Other';
        }
```