# php sendmail() from same domain - is it considered SPAM now?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to know if using PHPmailer functions to send HTML or plain emails
would be not considered as SPAM by mail servers if it would originate
from the domain with the same name.

For example :

- sending email with PHPmailer as "info@mydomain.com"
  originating from "mydomain.com" domain (as opposed to say GMail server or other mail servers).

I have a "password lost" system that sends emails to people using my website/portal
and so far i tested the function with my GMail account. I wonder that when I will move
to new hosting, linux box, and configure the domain on that box, and add a mail account and use PHPMailer locally, with that mail account, maybe it would be totally cleaner and will not go in SPAM folders when I sent mails.

Let me know your thoughts about it,
and if this really works

thanks,

Comment: Please see this question and answers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked

Answer (score 0):

Your mails originating from yourdomain.com sent as info@yourdomain.com will not be marked with "using domain yoursharedhostingdomain.com" in gmail, so mails shouldn`t drop in the spam folder for that reason.

With Gmail here i mean e-mail client, not using gmail account as a sender.

Comment: yes, using GMail, but in PHPMailer, the settings will be of the local account, so not using GMail. using the domain where I have the hosting, with the email account/pass from exactly that same domain. what then?  :)

Comment: this is how I will use it when i launch the site, so I hope mails will not go sometimes to SPAM, cause it's legit email sent from the same domain.