# Does dating an e-mail message prevent it being sent to the spam folder?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm with a doubt and I dont find reliable information about this, so I came here to ask you.

I'm using phpmailer class to send emails, and everything is working fine.

But I wanted to avoid that emails dont go to spam folder.

So I found some people saying if we use date in our message, avoid this.

This technique really works? And if yes, is really necessary? Even using phpmailer?

I'm asking this that because I think that all email providers, in every email, appears the date, so I think a bit repetitive to put also date in my email message.

Something Like this:

```
<p>Email sent at '.date('d/m/Y H:i:s').'</p>
```

Comment: That's total nonsense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked?rq=1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because handling possible spam problems is not a programming issue.

Comment: If this worked, every spammer would be doing it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every spam filter is different and uses its own approaches for identifying spam. It cannot be said for sure that any given technique will always work. If your emails are being detected as spam by many filters then there's probably **many** characteristics in your emails that are triggering the filters, not just any single factor.

All I can suggest to avoid your messages being marked as spam is to use a widely trusted SMTP server such as a commercial SMTP relay service (such as SendGrid, Google Gmail, etc) or bona-fide marketing email service (such as MailChimp, CmapaignMonitor, etc) as these services are less likely to be used by real spammers because they provide accountability and impose rate-limits.

I also suggest you look at the content of your messages and ensure that they don't contain any known (at this point, cliched) spam terms like 'shopping', 'watches', or 'enlarge your penis'.

Comment: Thanks, I'm much more enlightened now. And I realized that what I read about putting a date in the email message does not solve anything. We just need to use a realiable SMPT server and have good email messages, and thats what I'll doing now! Thank you :)