# Cannot send Email Confirmation to certain email providers

Tags: email, liferay-6

I have a Liferay 6.1.0ga1 Portal that requires email confirmation from new registered users.
Following my feedback from the Portal users, and testing with misc Email Providers I've noticed:

1. Users that use a `gmail` account for their account, have no problem at all
2. `Hotmail` users will receive the 'welcome to our portal' and 'Email confirmation' emails, directly into their junk folder
3. `Yahoo` users are receiving most of the sent emails (welcome email, reset pasword, etc) normally, but the email confirmation is never received, and cannot be found even in their Spam Folder. The same happens for every request for a new confirmation mail. In a certain case, the Confirmation email arrived a few hours later, but I cannot really reproduce this scenario.

This is becoming a blocker issue because yahoo users can't register to the portal.

Can anyone provide some ideas on what is causing this behavior, and how could I make sure that all users can receive their confirmation emails ?

---

Edit:

Could it be that certain email providers are using a strict policy, are blocking the Confirmation Email, because it includes an activation email? I've thought of some solutions like
 - Creating a register Hook that informs the new users that they could set their account to accept mails from my Portal
 - Creating a hook that will use another Email Template for email confirmation, e.g including the confirmation Token and excluding the activation url

Comment: Provide help information on confirming their email address within the portal itself so that users that have this problem can find information on how to resolve it (such as whitelisting). There's plenty of other tweaks you could try with the email formatting to try to get by this issue, but ultimately there's going to be a provider somewhere that rejects it anyway.

Comment: @THiCE Thanx a lot, you were right. it was a mail server dns issue. You can post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it

Comment: Okay then! I posted my comment as an answer and removed my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at this very old question: [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

So have you tried the mentioned options in the marked answer there?