# Why my email sent by my site is marked as spam in google and hotmail using codeigniter phpmailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

This is a redundant question.
I am using phpmailer codeigniter library in sending email. I can send and recieve email however when I received it, it is marked as spam.
I think this info can be useful:

```
public $Mailer = 'mail';
public $Hostname = 'http://www.fhi365.com/';
public $Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
public $Port        = 465;
public $SMTPSecure = "ssl";
public $SMTPAuth     = true;
```

What are the steps I need to do to solve this?
Thanks for help

Comment: Make sure your smtp server not black listed by the Email Clients.

Comment: Thanks for reply! How can I check if my smtp server is black listed or not?

Comment: And if use smtp.fhi365.com ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the issue of sending through server email servers.

For an email to be considered "safe" it has to meet A LOT of criteria, which, without full access to the server, I don't think can be configured.

First of all, you need to have [DKIM and SPF](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21751322-What-are-SPF-and-DKIM-and-do-I-need-to-set-them-up-) key signatures that are actually valid. They are needed for the email service provider to be sure that you aren't a scam.

Next, you from email and domain (from email is what is before the @, and domain is what is after the @) have to be safe. Which means that when you send emails, people actually open your letter. Because let's say I set up a simple php email sending script and send some inappropriate pictures or some evil-evil programs. That is why ESP by default put your email into spam. That's why on most websites on registration, you are asked to check your spam folder. The website's domain does not have enough "positive" reputation to be considered trusted by the major ESP. If one person moves your letter from spam to inbox, you get a small reputation boost - but you need a lot of it.

Next, is the sender. The IP of the sender also has to be trusted. If you are sending from a PC IP that is known for spamming, even if you have all the previous criteria all set up, it will still be spam box for you all the time. That is called domain warming. You need reputation for your IP as well.

There are also minor things such as email content (if it looks like a casual letter, you have more chances of getting into inbox), the amount of styling and pictures you have in there.

Bottom line - don't bother a lot with getting your email to inbox. If the user KNOWS he is getting your letter in the email, he will get it out of the spam folder. Just notify the user about the email and you will be set.