# How to solve the essue of Mail sending in spam in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

My Code is given below, My config details is:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Mail Part is given below:

```
$message="<table style='width:300px;'>";
$message.="<tr><td colspan='2'>Contact Information</td></tr>";
$message.="<tr><td>Name:</td><td>".$contname."</td></tr>";
$message.="<tr><td>Email:</td><td>".$contemail."</td></tr>";
$message.="<tr><td>Description:</td><td>".$contdesc."</td></tr>";
$this->email->from($contemail, $contname);
$this->email->to($admin_email); 
$this->email->subject('Contact Information from eminence System');
$this->email->message($message);    
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Do you mean instead of inbox it's going to spam folder?

Comment: yes.it moves on spam folder

Comment: I think it's not in control of our code.Google, Yahoo mail providers will decide or user need to add your mail address in their address book

Comment: it depends on your email subject also change it and check if its going in spam

Comment: which mail sending service are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

Answer (score -1):

What goes in your SPAM folder vs your inbox is not determined by your code. Spam Filters and firewalls work on many different levels to try to intelligently decide what is or is not spam.

A few things you can do to try to avoid your e-mails being dumped into SPAM are:

1. Adjust your Subject to be straight forward and descriptive of the email
2. Ensure that your FROM header is a valid email address that can be pingbacked successfully
3. Ensure that your host-server's IP address is not listed on any Blacklists

Good luck