# Can you correct this html code / php for my Contact Form?

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I need help with my Contact Form coding. I am working on a Dreamweaver CS6 website. Could you take a look at my code and see what is wrong with it? I think, the html is fully correct. There is an error on php coding.

Html:

```
  <form action="assets/styles/contact_form.php" method="post" class="ui-form form-contacts">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h2 class="ui-title-block">Get In Touch</h2>
          <div class="ui-subtitle-block">send us a message</div>
          <div class="border-color border-color_center"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="NAME" name="author" required class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="EMAIL" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="SUBJECT" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <textarea id="comment-text" name="comment" placeholder="COMMENT" required rows="9" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="text-right">
            <button class="btn">SEND<i class="icon fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user_name'])){
$author         = $_POST['user_name'];
$email      = $_POST['user_email'];
$to         = 'john@mybusiness.ca';
$subject    = $_POST['message_subject'];
$comment    = $_POST['message_content'];
$headers    = 'From: '. $author .' <'.$email.'>';

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'success';
}
else{
    echo 'fail';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Wait..... Have you ever made a form before?. Please try to look at the name attribute. They don't match with post keys. $_POST["user_name"] should be $_POST["author"];,

Comment: How do you know there is an error in the code?

Comment: Because I tested out the contact form by sending an email to myself through the contact form and I didn't receive an email.

Comment: I'm not an expert in PHP at all. I'm a beginner in PHP.

Comment: @SHE According to me your php code wouldn't have outputted any thing not even "fail"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a common thing. The name attribute you are using in your html code is not been used to get the value using post associative array. The value of input submitted by the from can only be extracted through a unique id or text. This is for what name attribute is used. Now to get the value we can use $_POST associative array and point to our input value by giving it the name attribute that we gave it in the previous page(html form). I hope i made my point clear. If you need some more assistant try to go to this link http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php. Try this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['author'])){
$author         = $_POST['author'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$to         = 'john@mybusiness.ca';
$subject    = $_POST['subject'];
$comment    = $_POST['comment'];
$headers    = 'From: '. $author .' <'.$email.'>';

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'success';
}
else{
    echo 'fail';
}
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: it would help everyone if you were to explain exactly "why" their code failed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Is this Ok

Comment: @SHE Did you got any output?. Any output, i think you would have get "fail". AM i right

Comment: @ShE I am glad that i helped. To get your mail go into inbox, you have to correctly setup your SMTP protocols and all. Try to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked

Comment: @SHE please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks it works now. It is coming in my Inbox now. Thank you for your help.