# Possible to learn if mail in spam ot not that i sent

Tags: c#, email, spam

In my application I am sending mails,
I want to know if mail I sent is in a spam folder of receiver or not, I searched a lot but couldn't find any way
**How can I learn it?**

Thanks for advices

Comment: This depends on user's mail settings. You _can't_ know that as far as I know. At least programmatically..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to learn , Every mail account such as outlook or gmail has different level spam filtering spam in outlook may not be spam in gmail.also people can set private spam filter to your mails,so nothing gives u a guarantee,u should read SMTP , and also u should improve new methods for example u should open a test accounts and when send mails send also these and u have idea what u will do

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only if you can access to your receiver's mail.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked) you can make some actions to prevent marking your mail as spam **but it is not 100% guarantee that your mail will not be marked as spam**

Answer (score 0):

You can check if various mail servers are filtering your mails to spam folder by checking on https://litmus.com/spam-filter-tests

They have free services for 3 providers including google. If your spam test fails there, that means the service providers are marking your emails as spam.