# How to prevent registraton e-mail from being treated as SPAM?

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer, spam

I have a website which sends e-mails to users on 2 occasions:

1. when they register then receive "hello there" e-mail
2. when they ask for a new password they receive a new password

Both e-mails are generated from a template, so all "register" e-mails look very similar. Also all "password reset" e-mails look alike.

And now I see they go directly to SPAM folders when sent to gmail accounts. 
When I display such a message from Gmail's SPAM folder I am notified they were treated as SPAM because Gmail already got lots of similar messages (and I know there were less than 30 of them sent).

So what can I do to be sure Gmail is NOT considering my e-mails as SPAM?

The "hello there" e-mail is not that necessary but the "password reset" ones are VERY important and there is no way to make them look different.

I use PhpMailer with SMTP.

I checked my e-mails with http://dkimvalidator.com/ and it says they are not blacklisted, have SPF and basically look fine. Nothing mentioned here:
[How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)
works for me and it's a thread that is 7 years old. And 7 years in computer science is really long. Therefore I think this is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: I would recommend looking into adding a DNS entry for an SPF text record. http://www.openspf.org/Introduction. If implemented properly, you will see a "mailed-by" line in gmail. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/180707?hl=en

Comment: @Scott: I changed SPF record on my domain. Now Gmail shows "mailed-by" properly but the messages still go to SPAM.