# Emails goes to spam when using domain name in tag

Tags: php, html, email, html-email, mail-server

I have Two domain. For Example: `domain1.com` and `domain2.com.` I am sending email using PHPMailer and I used

```
$email_body="<a href='http://www.domain1.com'>View</a>"
```

Above code is working perfectly and emails also go to inbox but when I am using my second domain instated of first then emails are going to spam.

```
$email_body="<a href='http://www.domain2.com'>View</a>"
```

Even I tried

```
"<a href='www.domain2.com'>View</a>"
"<a href='http://domain2.com'>View</a>"
```

If I remove domain2.com and type some dummy text then also emails go to inbox.
Would you help me in this?

Comment: They are probably getting picked up as spam

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.RiggsFolly, How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: @NarendraVerma Emails arriving from DomainA but urging users to go to DomainB are suspicious since they exhibit behaviour which is consistent with phishing emails. You can consider sending emails from domainB with a reply-to domainA instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.apokryfos, I am sending email from abc@gmail.com and when I am  using my first domain within anchor tag then emails go to inbox and when I am using my second domain the emails go to spam

Comment: Then it's probably something you need to sort out with the GMail team

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.apokryfos

Comment: Are you using CC mail id.. may be that is the reason it goes to spam. And add some different word between two links.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.selvan, I am not using CC mail id and I am using only one domain which is domain2. domain1 is working. I am getting issue only in domain2

Comment: Did you find any solution @NarendraVerma ?

Comment: Yes, Mr.Manish, I was getting the same issue then I make my domain secure and my issue got resolved. You have to make HTTPS 
 your domain and use https://www.example.com. It will work

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your domain again Safe Browsing list
https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.syl.fabre. I checked my both domain,  In the first domain it is showing "Not dangerous" and In the second domain is showing "No available data"