# How to change sender name different form authenticated email?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendmail, nodemailer

```
 var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// Not the movie transporter!
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
          user: '*****@gmail.com', // Your email id
          pass: '*******' // Your password
      }
  });




var mailOptions = {
           from: varfrom_name, // sender address
           to: varto, // list of receivers
           subject: varsubject, // Subject line
           text: vartext, // plaintext body
           html: varhtml // html body
       };


       console.log(mailOptions);

       // send mail with defined transport object
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
           if (error) {
               return console.log(error);
           }else{
             return console.log(info);
           }
       });
```

I want different sender address from the authenticated one ?
Suppose I authenticated data with abc@gmail.com, but I want to send the mail from xyz@gmail.com to def@gmail.com.
How to do that in node-mailer ?

```
// Using send mail npm module

var sendmail = require('sendmail')({silent: true})
      sendmail({
        from: ' xyz@gmail.com',
        to: 'def@gmail.comh',
        subject: 'MailComposer sendmail',
        html: 'Mail of test sendmail ',
        attachments: [
        ]
      }, function (err, reply) {
        console.log(err && err.stack)
        console.dir(reply)
      })
```

But the mails coming in the span box and the mails that we are sending  is won't showing in the sent mail of sender mail address ?

I hope i will able to elaborate my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Gmail does not allow the change of the sender address.

However, you can look for another service, like postmark, sendgrid, or create your own smtp server.