# sending mail with PHPmailer using gmail smtp is flagged as spam

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer, spam

When i try to send a  mail with PHPmailer via gmail smtp server the mail will be flagged as spam. i am using a hotmail account to receive the email.

i've looked to other topics about this problem but they mention that they set the "from" to their own domain name but for me myaccount@gmail.com is good enough.

this is the code i use:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$body             = "test";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;                  
$mail->Username   = "myaccount@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password   = "mypassword";            
$mail->SetFrom('myaccount@gmail.com', 'myaccount');
$mail->Subject    = "Test subject";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = "myaccount@hotmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "test"); 
$mail->Send()
```

I've read this topic: 
[How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

but like i said i don't need my own domain name. Or is this impossible and do i need to use my own domain and use SPF and DKIM?

**Edit:**

I've tested sending emails to yahoo and gmail and both work only hotmail will mark them as spam.

**Solved:**

I tried to send a mail with the gmail webclient and even then my mail gets flagged as spam. Somehow the gmail smtp servers are blacklisted. So i created an hotmail account and changed the code to use hotmail smpt server.

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";              
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.live.com';  
$mail->Port       = 587;
```

Now my mails are not marked as spam anymore on yahoo gmail and hotmail.

Comment: Yes! I am sorry. Best luck!

Comment: Look at the headers of a message you have received in hotmail - it will often say *why* a message has been marked as spam, such as for SPF or DKIM failure, though since you're sending from gmail using a gmail address, both of those should pass without you doing anything.

Comment: Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 209.85.208.66)
smtp.mailfrom=gmail.com; hotmail.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified)
header.d=gmail.com;hotmail.com; dmarc=pass action=none header.from=gmail.com;
Received-SPF: Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of gmail.com designates
209.85.208.66 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com;
client-ip=209.85.208.66; helo=mail-ed1-f66.google.com;
Received: from mail-ed1-f66.google.com (209.85.208.66) by
CO1NAM05FT062.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.96.180) with Microsoft SMTP
Server

Comment: i also use a custom domain in zoho, but ended up the same flagged output inside the receiver *gmail* no luck then. @Stan

Comment: i have the same problem ... not luck with it i have not solved it ... XD

Comment: You can also try to set the name of the sender to the email adres you are sending with (second parameter in the SetFrom() function) i noticed when doing this the email has more chance of being accepted.