# Laravel Sendgrid mail keeps going to spam

Tags: php, laravel, email, sendgrid, spam-prevention

### What I am Trying to accomplish

So I have created a laravel application called Enable Rochester that is essentially a directory of individuals for my city. In the application users can contact other users within the directory by submitting a captcha protected form with a subject and message field which then sends an email to the recipient.

### My Problem

To allow the users to contact each other I am using the senders email as the replyTo email and sender email within the email signature which seems to be a problem as all the emails sent are being sent to the users spam. Check out the email signature below:

```
from:   Solomon Antoine <antoinesolomon5@gmail.com> via sendgrid.net 
reply-to:   Solomon Antoine <antoinesolomon5@gmail.com>
to: contact@askfavr.com
date:   Feb 27, 2019, 11:31 AM
subject:    Coffee and Greet for Favr
mailed-by:  em3247.enablerochester.com
signed-by:  enablerochester.com
security:    Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more
```

### My Steps to try to solve the problem

The first step I took to try to mitigate the issue was changing the sender authentication from *sendgrid.net* to my domain *enablerochester.com* like below:

```
from:   Solomon Antoine <antoinesolomon5@gmail.com> via enablerochester.com 
reply-to:   Solomon Antoine <antoinesolomon5@gmail.com>
to: solomon@askfavr.com
date:   Feb 27, 2019, 11:50 AM
subject:    Testing with new domain
mailed-by:  em3247.enablerochester.com
signed-by:  enablerochester.com
security:    Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more
```

When that didn't work I tried to change the sender email to a custom sender email using my own domain like below:

```
from:   Solomon Antoine <antoinesolomon51@enablrochester.com> via enablerochester.com 
reply-to:   Solomon Antoine <antoinesolomon5@gmail.com>
to: support@askfavr.com
date:   Feb 27, 2019, 11:59 AM
subject:    Another test
mailed-by:  em3247.enablerochester.com
signed-by:  enablerochester.com
security:    Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more
```

I have referenced another [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked) which provided the steps above but the solution it offered does not work.

Comment: @john-conde can you read? I literally referenced that the duplicate's solution doesn't answer my question. You mods are so trigger happy to mark a question as a duplicate. God.

Comment: Since your domain doesn't even contain a SPF record, chances are you haven't fully read the reference. Unless this question contains more logs or spam testign service results than previous questions, there's no good reason to keep it open. Smearing all the my-mail-goes-to-spam answers thin across thousands of questions isn't very useful.